# Django: Querysets to get choices from a model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a simple appointment app that lets users sign up for unfilled timeslots. The user would select a date and query the database for timeslots that are available for that day. How would I make a query to get timeslots that are still available?

models.py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    TIMESLOT_LIST = (
        (1, '10:00 – 11:00'),
        (2, '11:00 – 12:00'),
        (3, '12:00 – 13:00'),
        (4, '13:00 – 14:00'),
        (5, '14:00 – 15:00'),
        (6, '15:00 – 16:00'),
        (7, '16:00 – 17:00'),
        (8, '17:00 – 18:00'),
        (8, '18:00 – 19:00'),
    )

    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    timeslot = models.IntegerField(choices=TIMESLOT_LIST, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def make_appointment(request):
    all_appointments = Appointment.objects.values_list('timeslot')
    appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    data_input = request.GET.get('date')

    available_appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(
        date = data_input
    ).exclude(timeslot = appointments).values_list(
        'timeslot'
    ).order_by('timeslot')

    return TemplateResponse(
        request,
        'scheduling/appointment.html',
        {
            "appointments" : appointments,
            "all_appointments" : all_appointments,
            "data_input": data_input
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could form a new list of the available times by doing;

```
available_appointments = [
    (value, time) for value, time in TIMESLOT_LIST if value not in all_appointments
]
```

Or if you want a tuple;

```
tuple(
    (value, time) for value, time in TIMESLOT_LIST if value not in all_appointments
)
```

You could then offer those choices in the template for people to choose from.

An example from the terminal;

```
>>> [(value, time) for value, time in TIMESLOT_LIST if value not in [1, 2, 3]]
[(4, '13:00 – 14:00'), (5, '14:00 – 15:00'), (6, '15:00 – 16:00'), (7, '16:00 – 17:00'), (8, '17:00 – 18:00'), (8, '18:00 – 19:00')]
```

Comment: So I made a minor edit to your answer. Instead of checking for values that are `not in all_appointments`, I checked for values that are `not in selected_date`. 

`selected_date = Appointment.objects.filter(date = data_input).values_list('timeslot')` 

I printed `selected_date` and `available_appointments` to the console and got the following: 

`<QuerySet [(1,)]>`


`[(1, '10:00 – 11:00'), (2, '11:00 – 12:00'), (3, '12:00 – 13:00'), (4, '13:00 – 14:00'), (5, '14:00 – 15:00'), (6, '15:00 – 16:00'), (7, '16:00 – 17:00'), (8, '17:00 – 18:00'), (8, '18:00 – 19:00')]`

Comment: So basically the issue is that the `available_appointments query` is NOT excluding the existing appointments. I think I'm very close to the answer but just can't seem to figure out the solution. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I just had to add `flat=True` to the `selected_date` query to return single values instead of tuples.